# Не могу получить преобразованное значение в виде строки

Tags: php, строки, преобразование

Есть у меня значение получаемое с админки `mac_key` которое состоит из букв, цифр и спецсимволов `df1u65%46&R%b*tm`. Если его присваиваю переменной напрямую `$mac_key = "df1u65%46&R%b*tm"`, то все работает хорошо. Но если вытягиваю из массива,

```
$mac_key = $this->mac_key;
```

то где-то возникает ошибка.. хотя var_dump показывает те же `string(20)` "df1u65%46&R%b*tm"

Как можно преобразовать к строке принудительно? Так не прокатывает:

```
$mac_key = strval($this->mac_key);
```

Comment: `$mac_key = (string) $this->mac_key;` ?

Comment: @Вася, а вас не очень смущает, что в строке `df1u65%46&R%b*tm` **всего 16 символов**, а функция var_dump() вам прямо говорит `string(20)`!?

Comment: А как идет определение переменной в классе?

Comment: @GrayHoax вот так `$this->mac_key = $this->get_option( 'mac_key' );`

Comment: @Visman да, еще как смущает! может, кавычки еще плюс ко всему считаются?

Comment: а если напрямую указывать, то var_dump указывает как раз-таки 16 символов, как и положено..что же делать, в чем подвох?

Comment: @Вася, выведите на экран `var_dump(bin2hex( $this->mac_key));` и по HEX кодам символов разберитесь, что у вас там прячется лишнее.

Comment: @Вася, задам вопрос по-другому, как определяется свойство `mac_key` в классе, согласно этой документации? http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: @Вася, для того, чтобы отобразить спец символ `&` в html его пишут в виде мнемоники `&amp;` Видимо у вас `$this->mac_key` возвращает строку подготовленную для отображения в html.

Comment: @Visman а есть какая-либо функция или процедура обратного преобразования для этого выражения

Comment: @Вася, http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php или http://php.net/manual/ru/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный ответ - декодировать получаемый набор символов `$mac_key = htmlspecialchars_decode($this->mac_key);` т.к. например `&` кодируется как `&amp;`

Answer (score 0):

У вас `$this->mac_key` не является массивом, это свойства некого класса. Но если проблема в типе данных, то попробуйте так:

```
$mac_key = (string)$this->mac_key;
```

Comment: нет, это не прокатывает..

Comment: Что var_dump выводит, скопируйте код.